# Positive lookahead character must only occur once and is optional

Tags: regex

```
^(?=.*[-_.]?)[a-z][a-z0-9-_.]{1,13}[a-z0-9]$
```

- Must start with a letter.
- Must end with a letter or digit.
- Must be between 3 and 15 characters long.
- May only exist of letters, digits and `[-_.]`.
- **`[-_.]` is optional, but when used must only occur ONCE in the entire string.**

I'm having trouble with the last bullet point.

Trying it with `(?=.*[-_.]?)` to lookahead and make sure that whenever `[-_.]` is used, it should only occur once. But it does not seem to work, because when I test it with a string like `a__-bc34` or `a.b_c-d` it matches, but it should only allow things like `a_bc34`.

Advanced regex is not my strongest so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: `[-_.]` is used three times in your example @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'do:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*[-_.]?[a-z0-9]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : start of string
(?=.{3,15}$)    : lookahead, assumes there is from 3 to 15 character
[a-z]           : a letter
[a-z0-9]*       : 0 or more alphanum
[-_.]?          : optional -, _ or .
[a-z0-9]+       : 1 or more alphanum
$               : end of string
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(?!([^-_.]*[-_.]){2})[a-z][\w.-]{1,13}[a-z0-9]$
```

"optional but max once" is logically equivalent to "not twice", and `(?!([^-_.]*[-_.]){2})` means just that.

The rest is your expression, but simplified by the use of `\w`, which is identical to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Also, putting restrictions like this in look aheads means you can easily add more such restrictions just by adding more look aheads. This is preferable to baking the requirement into the core expression.

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm choose Toto's answer since it provides some explanation.

Comment: @kid explanation added.